# Remove formulas from all worksheets in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm having toubles removing formulas from cells in Excel and keep only the value (in case there is a number). The problem is due to the fact that there are also pivot tables (and also GETPIVOTDATA cells) within the different spreadsheets.

I am currently trying this code but it only works on normal spreadsheets:

```
Sub fun()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim pc As PivotCell

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    With ws.UsedRange
        .Value = .Value
    End With
Next ws


For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
            For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
                pi.Value = pi.Value
            Next pi
        Next pf
    Next pt
Next ws

End Sub
```

Could you help me to adapt the code so that every cell will be set to value?!

Comment: You didn't ask a question. Please ask a question according [ask]. Also include a [mcve] with example data or screenshots. Note that *"not working"* is no usfull error description. Instead explain what does not work and what happens instead of what you expect it to happen.

Comment: Did you try copy and "paste as values" for pivot tables instead of `pi.Value = pi.Value`? Because `pi.Value = pi.Value` will only turn formulas into values.

Comment: Pivot Table cells already display values and not formulas. Why do you need to replace them?

Comment: Yes, but you can use the values in the pivot table to generate formulas in other cells of the same spreadsheet...and those cells won't be set to a value by running this code. It is like the sheets with pivot tables are not included in the analysis, or it seems so.

Comment: No, `pi.Value = pi.Value` will only turn formulas into values. So if you have no formulas in your pivot tabves nothing will happen to the pivots. What do you expect to happen with the pivot tables?

Answer (score 2):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, a, area As String
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        a = ws.UsedRange
        area = ws.UsedRange.Address
        ws.Cells.ClearContents
        ws.Range(area) = a
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I would limit this to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` or something. This run on the wrong workbook (if you have multiple workbooks open) and you can't go back (undo doesn't work with vba)! So, careful you must be :)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ it is true